# Loading Handlebars from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am writing an EmberJS project in which I want to load Handlebars templates from Javascript instead of creating them in the html file.

Here's the code currently like:

```
<body>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='template1'>
   ...
</script>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='template2'>
   ...
</script>
<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='template3'>
   ...
</script>
<body>
```

However, I am using requirejs to keep my project modular and I want to be able to load the template through a .js file

I've checked out the `Handlebars.compile(source)` call, but it doesn't actually get the template registered with a name, for emberjs code, to be able to access. Also, please share some insights on keeping emberjs projects modular.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer - if this is a new Ember project, please use Ember App Kit or the new ember-cli.
We're using something like this for template loading:

```
define({
    requireTemplate: function (url, name) {
       $.ajax({url: url,
           async: false,
           success: function(templateText) {
               var compiledTemplate = Ember.Handlebars.compile(templateText);
               Ember.TEMPLATES[name] = compiledTemplate;
           }
       });
    }
})
```

and using this we iterate over all the templates (which can be serialised from a directory).
As for keeping the project modular - again, please use either Ember App Kit or ember-cli.